# Fixing my workflow on converting bounding box(object detection) to actual coordinates based on .tfw

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am trying to convert the Yolov8 detected bounding box locations to actual coordinates and export them to ArcGIS or other GIS software as point data. I'm working on Windows 11 Python 3.9. It kind of works but the result is not so accurate. What may I have done wrong?

Below are the files I have:

- Original TIF (1082x1352,32bit, LZW)
- TFW for the TIF
- TXT from YOLOv8 detection (bounding box)

You can download these sample files here:https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hTsu3ic0NecEBS3zqrvBlcM7Ye6cHmBn?usp=sharing

My workflow goes as follows:

1. From TXT file, extract  and Y coordinates of center of the bounding box

For example, if the TXT data looks like: 1   0.551792   0.522016   0.109088   0.0823766, it means Xcenter is at 55.1792% of the image and Ycenter is at 52.2016% of the image (1 is object ID, 0.109088 0.0823766 are width and height)

2. Read projected coordinates from TFW

TFW provides X and Y center coordinate of the left top pixel of the TIF, in this case
390814.4999800899 and 4551345.5003344063.

3. Convert XY values to georeferenced coordinates.

The Python code I used is:

```
import os
from osgeo import gdal

# Input directory A containing .tfw and .tif files
input_dir_a = r'C:\Users\raster'

# Input directory B containing mid-point text files
input_dir_b = r'C:\Users\raster\labels'

# Output directory to save processed files
output_dir = r'C:\Users\result'

# Create the output directory if it doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
    os.makedirs(output_dir)

# Function to convert pixel coordinates to actual coordinates using GDAL
def pixel_to_geocoordinate(tif_path, text_file_path):
    # Open the TIF file with GDAL to extract geospatial information
    ds = gdal.Open(tif_path)
    
    if ds is None:
        print(f"Failed to open {tif_path}. Skipping.")
        return
    
    geo_transform = ds.GetGeoTransform()
    x_origin = geo_transform[0]
    y_origin = geo_transform[3]
    
    # Read pixel coordinates from the text file
    with open(text_file_path, 'r') as text_file:
        pixel_coordinates = [line.strip().split() for line in text_file]

    # Convert pixel coordinates to actual coordinates
    actual_coordinates = []
    for item in pixel_coordinates:
        if len(item) >= 3:
            x_pixel = float(item[1])
            y_pixel = float(item[2])
            x_actual = x_origin + (x_pixel * geo_transform[1])
            y_actual = y_origin - (y_pixel * geo_transform[5])
            actual_coordinates.append((x_actual, y_actual))

    return actual_coordinates

# Get the list of filenames in Folder A
file_names_a = set()
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_dir_a):
    for file_name in files:
        if file_name.endswith((".tfw", ".tif")):
            base_name = os.path.splitext(file_name)[0]
            file_names_a.add(base_name)

# Process only the matching files in Folder B
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_dir_b):
    for file_name in files:
        if file_name.endswith(".txt"):
            base_name = os.path.splitext(file_name)[0]
            if base_name in file_names_a:
                tif_file_path = os.path.join(input_dir_a, base_name + ".tif")
                output_filename = base_name + "_cor.txt"
                output_path = os.path.join(output_dir, output_filename)
                actual_coordinates = pixel_to_geocoordinate(tif_file_path, os.path.join(input_dir_b, file_name))
                
                if actual_coordinates:
                    with open(output_path, 'w') as output_file:
                        for x, y in actual_coordinates:
                            output_file.write(f"{x}, {y}\n")
                    print(f"Processed: {file_name} and saved to {output_filename}")

print(f"Processing complete. Output files are saved in the '{output_dir}' directory.")
```